# How to run and extract an embedded python volume using TrueCrypt?

Tags: python, truecrypt

I have a Python script that has hidden results and need to apply it to TrueCrypt and generate a TrueCrypt volume that has hidden content. How do I execute the script in Python to produce the video?

I have tried python 'tcsteg.py' and 'cd path/to/tcsteg.py' with still no results. I ran the program first (tcsteg.py) and then tried executing these strings but I cannot execute the code. I was able to execute in cmd with the following results:

Usage: tcsteg.py  
Embeds a file into a TrueCrypt container so that both are still readable.

is a file in one of the following formats:
QuickTime / ISO MPEG-4  (*.m4a, *.m4v, *.mov, *.mp4, *.qt)

is a TrueCrypt container containing a hidden volume. The file will be
modified in-place so that it seems like a copy of the input file that can be
opened in an appropriate viewer/player. However, the hidden TrueCtype volume
will also be preserved and can be used.